# nvidia gpu error?

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia

I'm ging to preface this with the fact that I'm a complete linux newbie and have no idea what I'm doing.

My computer has been running fine with ubuntu. I recently installed awesome wm but wanted to delete it, so I ran a command purging awesome. I imagine I messed something up in that process. anyways now I get presented with the error

```
nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2 timeout error e0000000
```

and a few others which I think are the product of this one. please help I have no clue what to do

Specs:
Alienware m18
Ubuntu 22.10
Nvidia gpu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Awesome WM deleted critical file system, here what you can do to fix that:

Boot into recovery mode: Restart your computer and hold down the Shift key during boot to access the GRUB menu. From there, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select the recovery mode option for your current kernel version.

Select the option to repair broken packages: Once you're in recovery mode, select the option to repair broken packages. This will attempt to fix any broken dependencies or missing packages that may be causing the issue.

Reinstall the Nvidia drivers: Since you mentioned that you have an Nvidia GPU, it's possible that the driver may have been affected by the purge command. You can try reinstalling the Nvidia drivers using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver
```

This will install the latest version of the Nvidia driver that is compatible with your system.

Reboot: Once you've completed the above steps, reboot your system and see if the issue has been resolved.

If it does not work come back with more information of your problem so we can help you